# Construct a function from the table with values and results

Tags: boolean-logic, symbolic-math, declarative

There are algorithms to convert truth table with multiple variable to a DNF (Disjunctive normal form). Is there a similar concept which can be generalized for variables taking a limited set of values?

For example, from this truth table we can compose DNF:

(¬A∧¬B∧¬D) ∨ (¬A∧B∧C) ∨ (A∧B∧D) ∨ (A∧¬B∧¬C)
[image]

Is there any automatic tools or algorithms which might help me to convert tables like this:

[image]

into the list of predicates composed of OR, AND, = ?

Result:

- (a = A2) -> 1
- ((a = A3) AND (b = B2)) -> 1
- otherwise -> 0

Each variable have a limited set of possible values. In my case I have 3 variable, each of them can take up to 30 different values.